# jQuery element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any significant performance differences these two blocks of code?

```
var element = $("#some-element");

SomeMethod1(element);
SomeMethod2(element);
SomeMethod3(element);
```

and...

```
SomeMethod1($("#some-element"));
SomeMethod2($("#some-element"));
SomeMethod3($("#some-element"));
```

Comment: Dunno if there's a big performance difference (this is on the client, unless your page is already unmanageably large, does it matter?) but as I understand it, the second method is recommended.  Setting a jQuery object to reference a part of the DOM can lead to some unintended behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by `significant`.

The first code snippet will always be faster than the second, because calling `$()` more than once has a cost (as jQuery does not cache the results of previous calls). Whether it's significant or not depends on your performance requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This does the element lookup in DOM and creates a jQuery object.

```
var element = $("#some-element");
```

In the first one, it ***reuses*** this object.

In second one, it has to do the ***lookup and creation 3 times***, hence the first one is better performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

It is not significant but not negligible also. In this case since you are using id selector it  will not make much difference but if you going to use class selector or attribute selector then it will make a big difference.

The first one will always give you better performance than the second one because you are reusing the same object at multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First one is faster, second is slower

Why?

Because first searchs for element only once, second three times

Answer (score 0):

Latter:

1. 3 string creations (the string literal holding the selector)
2. 3 function calls to `$()`, each of which result in more function calls within
3. 3 searches of the document for the same element

Given the type of selector being used, I wouldn't say it's *significant*, but the latter requires more processing time and uses more memory (see above list). And that stuff adds up over the size of an app.

With a less direct selector, it could become significant much more quickly.

**Edit:** The latter, however, is ugly and drives me nuts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first snippet reuses the first call to `$("#some-element")` whilst the other example needs to lookup the `#some-element` three times.